# Retrieving properties of redirected resource

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

How can I retrieve all the properties of http://dbpedia.org/resource/Milano? I tried with this query but I have a few results and I don't understand the reason:

```
select ?prop ?c 
where {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Milano> ?prop ?c.}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?prop%20?c%20%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Milano%3E%20?prop%20?c.%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Can we see the whole query please (+ prefixes etc)? Was this against the public endpoint at dbpedia?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the problem is?  That query returns 10 results, but I assume you're looking for all the information about Milano, is that correct?  The Wikipedia page Milano redirects to the page for Milan, and it's the DBpedia resource Milan that has most of the information.  I've posted an answer based on this assumption.  If you can confirm that this is what you're asking, then we can update the question with some clarification (making it more likely to be found by future users).

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 3):

The question isn't entirely clear, but expect that the problem you're asking about is why you're getting triples about `dbpedia:Milano`, but not `dbpedia:Milan`.  This query, as you can see in the results, only returns ten rows:

```
select ?prop ?c
where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Milano> ?prop ?c.
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?prop%20?c%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Milano%3E%20?prop%20?c.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

One of those rows, however, is

```
prop                                          c
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects http://dbpedia.org/resource/Milan
```

So, the simple answer is "query for Milan" with a query like this:

```
select ?prop ?c
where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Milan> ?prop ?c.  # you can use dbpedia:Milan, too
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?prop%20?c%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Milan%3E%20?prop%20?c.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

A more sophisticated answer would return the triples for `dbpedia:Milano` *and* any triples of anything that it redirects to (and, I suppose, anything that any of those redirect to, and so on, though I think that Wikipedia limits redirects to be one level deep).  You can do this with a property path query in SPARQL:

```
select ?prop ?c
where {
  dbpedia:Milano dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects* ?subject .
  ?subject ?prop ?c.
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?prop%20?c%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aMilano%20dbpedia-owl%3awikiPageRedirects%2a%20?subject%20.%0D%0A%20%20?subject%20?prop%20?c.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

In that query `?subject` will be anything related by a path of length zero or more (so, given the data that we've seen, `?subject` will be bound to at least `dbpedia:Milano` and `dbpedia:Milan`.  If you want to preserve information about the subject of the various triples that you're using, you might want to add `?subject` to the `select` line, so as to have `select ?subject ?prop ?c`.

If you don't care about the particular value of `?subject`, then you actually don't need to bind `?subject` at all, and could use a blank node in the query:

```
select ?prop ?c
where {
  dbpedia:Milano dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects* [ ?prop ?c ] .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?prop%20?c%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aMilano%20dbpedia-owl%3awikiPageRedirects%2a%20%5B%20?prop%20?c%20%5D%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

#### Caveat

Unfortunately, although this last query is legal SPARQL, Virtuoso says it's an error. Fortunately, this last refinement is entirely optional;  it's not vital to the solution.  If you were querying against a different endpoint, you'd be able to use it.  The error that Virtuoso gives is:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Object of transitive triple pattern should be variable or QName or literal, not blank node

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 define input:default-graph-uri <http://dbpedia.org> select ?prop ?c
where {
  dbpedia:Milano dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects* [ ?prop ?c ] .
}
```

I contacted the Virtuoso mailing list and they confirmed that it's a Virtuoso bug, and that they'll fix it.  I don't know how long it will take for the fix to get to the DBpedia endpoint, though.

Comment: I [asked about this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201310.mbox/%3C525D3AA4.9010204%40apache.org%3E) on the Jena users' mailing list, and got a response that the query should be OK.  Now I've sent a message to the Virtuoso mailing list, and am awaiting a response…

Comment: Just replied to your email, this form of query is legal so it is Virtuoso which has a bug

Comment: @RobV I love internet turn around times; Dave Reynolds and Andy Seaborne replied very quickly, too. I'm now awaiting to hear from Virtuoso people.