# return full wikipedia page for a query using dbpedia

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia

I am using the following Code to retrieve disambiguation pages for a given query.

```
#disambiguation function
def disambiguation(name, sparql):
  query = "SELECT DISTINCT ?syn WHERE { { ?disPage dbpedia-owl:wikiPageDisambiguates <http://dbpedia.org/resource/"+name+"> . ?disPage dbpedia-owl:wikiPageDisambiguates ?syn . }  UNION {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/"+name+"> dbpedia-owl:wikiPageDisambiguates ?syn . } }"
  sparql.setQuery(query)
  sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)  
  results_list = sparql.query().convert()
  return results_list
```

---

Question:

> Is it possible to return the full wikipedia page for every element in the results_list?

Comment: "Is it possible to return the full wikipedia page for every element in the results_list?"  What do you mean "return the full Wikipedia page"?  DBpedia doesn't store Wikipedia pages;  it stores data extracted from them.  You can retrieve the information from the corresponding DBpedia resources, though.

Comment: You may find [Retrieving properties of redirected resource](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19380175/1281433) helpful.

Comment: I actually wanted to retrieve the whole wikipedia page. For example: When I find a name in a different language I want to Go to the corresponding wikipedia page and retrieve its corresponding page

Comment: You didn't mention anything about Go in the question; you only asked for SPARQL and Python.

Comment: correct me. IF i return the link for the corresponding wikipedia page then I can retrieve the text there correct?

Comment: Yes, see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simplifying your query

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT ?syn WHERE {
>   { ?disPage dbpedia-owl:wikiPageDisambiguates <http://dbpedia.org/resource/"+name+"> .
>     ?disPage dbpedia-owl:wikiPageDisambiguates ?syn . }
>   UNION
>   { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/"+name+"> dbpedia-owl:wikiPageDisambiguates ?syn . }
> }
> ```

This query can be more cleanly written as

```sql
select distinct ?syn where {
  ?syn (dbpedia-owl:wikiPageDisambiguates|^dbpedia-owl:wikiPageDisambiguates)* dbpedia:name
}
```

This query says to find everything that's connected to **dbpedia:name** by a path of **dbpedia-owl:wikiPageDisambiguates** properties in any direction.

### Getting the Wikipedia article URL

> [I actually wanted to retrieve the whole wikipedia page. For example:
>   When I find a name in a different language I want to Go to the
>   corresponding wikipedia page and retrieve its corresponding page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679718/return-full-wikipedia-page-for-a-query-using-dbpedia/28680990#comment45661828_28679718)

If you actually want to retrieve the page (using some other library, or whatever you have), then you just need to get the Wikipedia article URL.  That's the value of the **foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf** property.  E.g., if you look at property values for [Johnny Cash](http://dbpedia.org/page/Johnny_Cash), you'll see

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Johnny_Cash foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Cash
```

Based on that, it sounds like you'd want a query more like:

```sql
select distinct ?page where {
  ?syn (dbpedia-owl:wikiPageDisambiguates|^dbpedia-owl:wikiPageDisambiguates)* dbpedia:name ;
       foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?page

}
```

Then each value of **?page** should be a Wikipedia article URL that you can download.

Comment: In rare cases like [Grammy Award winners](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Grammy_Award_winners), you need to fall back on `prov:wasDerivedFrom`.